# What does (== " ") mean, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, boolean

To the vultures who might say "Look it up in your textbook", or "Hoogle it", I did.

I came across the statement

`recipe = (== "000001")`

It looks like some sort of boolean to me but I'm not sure. I've tried testing it in different ways in GHCi but I couldn't figure out anything that works. 
Can  someone explain what it means, and this question will be a result the next time someone Googles *Haskell (==" ")*

Comment: 'this question will be a result the next time someone Googles "Haskell (=="'  No, it won't. Google ignores punctuations, googling for "Haskell (==" is the same as just googling "Haskell". That also explains why you didn't get any useful when searching for this.

Comment: it's just checking the equality of a string.  Try ghci>recipe "000001" and it will return True

Comment: @sepp2k THat's interesting... can you explain how I would Google such a thing?

Comment: @Imray Sorry for the bad edit.

Comment: @Imray I wish I knew. Anything involving punctuation is incredibly frustrating to Google. With these kind of things, just asking is sometimes the only thing you can do - even if it has been asked a million times before - there's just no way to find it.

Comment: Just wanted to add, although it is useless in this case it might be in the future http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords

Comment: Tip: When searching for operators (functions with non-alphanumeric names) in Hayoo or Hoogle, enclose them in parentheses: (==).

Comment: When I see a statement beginning with "To the vultures ...", I feel less inclined to write an answer. Please overcome your defensiveness about this, both for the sake of finding an answer, and for your own peace of mind. Just write "I have googled and hoogled this, but couldn't find an answer" somewhere in your post. This improves your chance of getting an answer, and if you frame it this way, you will reduce your feeling of there being some "vultures" out there. I am not sure I formulated this in the right way, but I hope you understand.

Comment: @Boris The awesome helpful Haskell people on this site knew what I was referring to. Often I get comments "Did you Google it?" and downvotes from people who put no thought into the question. I guess I was expressing frustration, but I understand what you are saying. I shouldn't have been negative, especially in an environment where people are so giving and helpful. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `GHCI` to figure this one out.

In `GHCI`, put in `let recipe = (== "000001")`. Now we can see how it works. Try `:t recipe` to see what the type is. That returns `recipe :: [Char] -> Bool`, so it looks like this is a function that takes an list of `Char`s (a `String`) and returns a `Bool`.

If you test it, you'll find it returns `False` for any input except `"000001"`.

Since `==` is an operator, you can partially apply it to one argument, and it will return a function that takes the other argument and returns the result. So here `== "000001"` returns a function that takes one argument to fill in the other side of the `==` and returns the result.

---

Edit: If the definition were `recipe = ((==) "000001")` this explanation would be right.

To understand this, you should look up [partial application](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application). The type of the `==` function is `a -> a -> Bool`, a function that takes two arguments of the same type and returns a `Bool`.

But it's also a function of type `a -> (a -> Bool)`, that takes one argument of type `a` and returns a new function with the signature `a -> Bool`. That's what's happening here. We've supplied one argument to `==`, so it returned a new function of type `a -> Bool`, or `[Char] -> Bool` in this particular case.

Comment: It's not currying. Well, not directly

Comment: No, that's not what's happening here. `(== foo)` fixes the *second* argument of `==`, not the first. So it's not just calling `==` with an argument.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, I'll fix that.

Comment: You're welcome, but my explanation was wrong before. It should be better now I think.

Comment: you overfixed it. :) the explanation is still right because `(==)` is symmetrical: `(== "001")` is exactly the same as `("001" ==)`. There is no difference.

Comment: @WillNess There is a difference and handwaving it away because it happens to work for this one operator is bad.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus There is absolutely no difference in this specific case. This is what I said, nothing more.

Comment: @WillNess There's no difference in the result here, but I think it's still good to explain the distinction in case people go on to test `func = (< 5)` or whatever. Also it originally said currying instead of partial application, so it was wrong regardless.

Comment: So, is the explanation correct with only ((==) "000001") or with both ((==) "000001") and (== "000001") ?

Comment: `(==) "000001"` is just an example of normal partial application that can be done with any multi-argument function. `== "000001"` is a special type of partial application called a section that can only be done with operators. In this case, since the order of the arguments of `==` doesn't matter, using partial application or an operator section has the same result. `(==) "000001"` and `== "000001"` are equivalent. However, `(<) 5` and `< 5` are not equivalent. The first is partial application and the second is a section, and they return different functions.

Answer (score 28):

It's a [section](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator). It's equivalent to `recipe = \x -> x == "000001"` (which in turn is the same as `recipe x = x == "000001"`).

Answer (score 7):

For binary operator `@` the expression `(@ x)` would mean `(\y -> y @ x)`.

In your case it will be `(\y -> y == "000001")` ie. function that takes String and says if it is equal to `"000001"`.

Answer (score 5):

`(== arg)` or `(arg ==)` is an operator section (it works for other operators as well - not just `==`). What it does is to partially apply the operator to the given operand. So `(== "foo")` is the same as `\x -> x == "foo"`.